# map TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python-3.x, csv, map, plotly, str

Quiero crear un diagrama sankey con la biblioteca plotly siguiendo las instrucciones de este video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yyVwvBUFRwY&t=661s
pero cuando intento ejecutar el código en el minuto 10:48.

`links['source'] = links['source'].map('mapping_dict')`

`links['target'] = links['target'].map('mapping_dict')`

Obtengo: TypeError: 'str' object is not callable,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tambien intente con el metedo get:

`links['source'] = [mapping_dict.get(x, x) for x in links['source']]`

`links['target'] = [mapping_dict.get(x, x) for x in links['target']]`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y no sé si el error persiste porque no arroja error cuando lo corro, pero al intentar graficar con plotly no muestra nada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui es como se ve el excel:

[image: EHNA-BASAL is my source and EHGNA-FINAL is my target]

Este es el código completo:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('BASE_PARA_GRAFICA.csv')
df.head()

df_template = df.groupby(['EHNA-BASAL', 'SEXO'])['INICIALES'].count().reset_index()
df_template.columns = ('source', 'target', 'value')
df_template


df_template['source'] = df_template.source.map({1:'LEVE', 2:'MODERADO', 3:'SEVERO'})
df_template

df_template2 = df.groupby(['SEXO', 'EHGNA-FINAL'])['INICIALES'].count().reset_index()
df_template2.columns = ('source', 'target', 'value')
df_template2


df_template2['target'] = df_template2.target.map({1:'NORMAL-FINAL', 2:'LEVE-FINAL', 3:'MODERADO-FINAL', 4:'SEVERO-FINAL'})
df_template2

links = pd.concat([df_template, df_template2], axis=0)
links

unique_source_target = list(pd.unique(links[['source','target']].values.ravel('K')))
unique_source_target

mapping_dict = {k: v for k, v in enumerate(unique_source_target)}
mapping_dict

#Aqui es donde me da el error, esta igual que en el video
links['source'] = links['source'].map('mapping_dict')
links['target'] = links['target'].map('mapping_dict')

#En lugar del anterior ejecuto este y me permite continuar pero cuando grafico no me muestra nada
links['source'] = [mapping_dict.get(x, x) for x in links['source']]
links['target'] = [mapping_dict.get(x, x) for x in links['target']]
links

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Sankey(
    node = dict(
        pad = 15,
        thickness = 20,
        line = dict(color = 'black', width = 0.5),
        label = unique_source_target,
        color = 'blue'
    ),

    link = dict(
        source = links_dict['source'],
        target = links_dict['target'],
        value = links_dict['value'],
    )
)]
)


fig.update_layout(title_text = 'Diferencia Basal - Final', font_size = 10)
fig.show()
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Haz clic en [edit] y traduce tu pregunta al castellano o terminará cerrada. Además, el código, los mensajes de error y salidas por consola deben or en formato texto y no en imágenes.

Answer (score 1):

El error te lo está dando porque estás pasando a la función '.map' el string "mapping_dict" en vez de un diccionario. Para solucionarlo únicamente quita las comillas para pasarle el valor de la variable 'mapping_dict'.

```
links['source'] = links['source'].map(mapping_dict)
links['target'] = links['target'].map(mapping_dict)
```